# Restoring Windows XP in bootloader after Windows 7 installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, bootloader

I'm trying to restore my Windows XP installation by making it bootable again. Windows 7 took control over the bootloader.

I'm using EasyBCD to update the Windows 7 bootloader however I cannot make the Windows XP entry (second one) point to D:\ (where it is installed). EasyBCD always enters C:\ just like the Windows 7 (which is the one on C:), even when I manually assign D:\ in EasyBCD when adding a new entry. **Am I doing something wrong? Is my Disk Management showing something which might be wrong?**

[image: EasyBCD]

[image: Disk management]

Comment: On image we see that EasyBCD uses Easyldr (renamed ntldr). Complete copyright infringement.

Answer (score 1):

It's *supposed* to be C:\

That's not the drive that Windows is on, it's the drive that easyldr or ntldr is on. Don't mess with it. Add the entry from the "Add New Entry" page with the checkbox for auto-detection checked or by manually choosing D: from the drop-down, *and don't play with anything else*. Just reboot and it'll work.

Comment: Why easyldr ? Easyldr is a renamed ntldr! What about copyright ???

Answer (score 0):

Did you manually add the entry for XP?

http://neosmart.net/gallery/photo/view/neosmart/EasyBCD/EasyBCD+2.0/Add+Entry+Windows+XP+manual/

more screenshots
http://neosmart.net/gallery/album/view/neosmart/EasyBCD/EasyBCD+2.0/

Comment: Uuhm: "even when I manually assign D:\ in EasyBCD when adding a new entry". So yes :)

Comment: @Moab, Easyldr is a renamed ntldr. What about copyright ?

Comment: @snayob I have no clue as I am not a copyright lawyer, but I think you are a troll commenting on a question started in 2010.

Comment: @Moab, you don't need to be lawyer to check if ntldr=easyldr. Refrain from categorizing somebody you don't know as troll ! My statement is simple - "easyldr is a renamed ntldr".